# How to make hero slider go always in the same direction

Tags: jquery, css

When slider arrive to last image, it goes to first image, witch is fine. The only problem is, it goes to the first image with a different effect(not moving to left like always, but moving to right)... how to make the same effect for all slides? (for cd-full-width)
(The images are moving to left,except the last one.The transition from last to first goes with an opposite efect...)

Hero Slider : http://codyhouse.co/gem/hero-slider/

I can't understand, is it from js or from css... It seems like its from css but i just don't see from where...

it should be an translateX effect, but i can't find the right one..

Comment: tried to change the translateX values, but nothing close to what i need..Do you have any idea?

Comment: could be something in js code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience with JQuery sliders:

The slides are held within a HTML list. The code navigates to each list item in order, pushing one out of view to get to the next. Well, once it reaches the end, the only way is backwards, so it has to retract to go back. It is more complicated to do this another way. So it is not so much that it has a different effect, it is just doing what it is told to do.

The code is somewhere in here:

```
$('.cd-slider-nav li').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var selectedItem = $(this);
    if(!selectedItem.hasClass('selected')) {
        // if it's not already selected
        var selectedPosition = selectedItem.index(),
            activePosition = $('.cd-hero-slider .selected').index();
        if( activePosition < selectedPosition) {
            nextSlide($('.cd-hero-slider'), $('.cd-slider-nav'), selectedPosition);
        } else {
            prevSlide($('.cd-hero-slider'), $('.cd-slider-nav'), selectedPosition);
        }

        updateNavigationMarker(selectedPosition+1);
    }
});
```

Basically, when it gets to the end of the list, it goes back to the beginning, and like I said, it visually shows this.

So yes, the CSS is specifying how it is moving left and right, but it is the JQuery that is telling it to go back to slide 1 at the end, using the style created by the CSS to move left and right.

To make all the same, you'll have an easier time finding another slider. This one is designed to do what it is designed to do. You would have to totally change the CSS and JS to make it do anything different.

There are countless JQuery sliders out there all with their own animations and perks about them. It shouldn't be hard to find one that fits your need.

Comment: i'm ok with going back to slide 1, i just don't like the visual effect when it goes to first slide. It is different from others.. But i can't find that effect in css..

Comment: Each slide, being in a list, is sitting side by side. The animation is changing the view. So when you go to slide 2 from slide one, slide one moves left out of view, and slide 2 moves left into view. This slider isn't designed to go in a circle and they generally aren't. I believe it is possible, but again, it would require completely changing the code to the point where you might as well find a new slider.